# Working Django Sybase driver

Tags: python, django, sybase, sqlanywhere

I need to connect to a remote Sybase Database, but I can't find a working driver which works without the Sybase sqlanywhere Library (because it was discontinued).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to connect against Sybase ASE, then in the past I've had success using [sybasemodule](http://python-sybase.sourceforge.net), compiled against [freetds](http://www.freetds.org).

Comment: doesn't the sybase module need the sybase librarys? http://python-sybase.sourceforge.net/sybase/node4.html

Comment: No, `freetds` is an open source replacement for sybase's `libct`